# swift parse query orderbyDescending doesn't work

Tags: swift, parse-platform, sql-order-by

I am using swift and parse. I used 'query.orderbyDescending' but in some way it doesn't work perfectly. I want to arrange the people's total score but the order looks like this (e.g., 9, 7, 32, 21, 15....). Seems like the coding recognize the first digit of the number. How can I fix it? Here's my codes.
Thank you!

```
class IndividualStatsTVC: UITableViewController {

var postsArray = [PFObject]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background2.png")!)
    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
     fetchData()
    print(postsArray)
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return postsArray.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("IndiStats", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! IndividualStatsTVCell

    cell.yourname?.text = postsArray[indexPath.row].objectForKey("Name") as? String
    cell.label1?.text = postsArray[indexPath.row].objectForKey("WIN") as? String
    cell.label2?.text = postsArray[indexPath.row].objectForKey("DRAW") as? String
    cell.label3?.text = postsArray[indexPath.row].objectForKey("LOSE") as? String
    cell.label4?.text = postsArray[indexPath.row].objectForKey("AceError") as? String
    cell.label5?.text = postsArray[indexPath.row].objectForKey("TOTAL") as? String
    return cell
}

//cell color
func colorForIndex(index: Int) -> UIColor {
    let itemCount = postsArray.count - 1
    let color = (CGFloat(index) / CGFloat(itemCount)) * 1.0
    return UIColor(red: 1.0, green: color, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.1)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell,
    forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = colorForIndex(indexPath.row)
}

func fetchData(){
    //empty postsArray
    postsArray = []
    //bring data from parse
    let query = PFQuery(className: "IndividualStats")
   query.orderByDescending("TOTAL")
    // postsArray.sortInPlace({($0["TOTAL"] as! Int) > ($1["TOTAL"] as! Int)})
   query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil && objects != nil{
            for object in objects! {
                self.postsArray.append(object)
                print(self.postsArray)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems `TOTAL` is a `String`. If so, the sort order is what would be expected. You need to store `TOTAL` as a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `orderBySortDescriptor:` which makes use of NSSortDescriptor. It automatically handles the sorting.